# TYPO3 v10 - absolute links - config.absRefPrefix dead?

Tags: hyperlink, typo3, absolute, typo3-10.x

How to tell TYPO3 v10 (globally) to generate absolute links in frontend? `config.absRefPrefix` doesn't seem to work any longer. Also, using absolute urls as `base` in `site configuration` doesn't have any effect. Still relative links in frontend.

EDIT:
`config.absRefPrefix` seems to work for embedded resources (script, img etc.) but not for usually generated hyperlinks (`MenuProcessor`, RTE links etc.). Do i really need to set option `absolute=1` for all my links generated by view helpers and configure RTE processing to generate absolute links? Thought that's why the global option "absRefPrefix" exists...

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: I could not solve it yet

Answer (score 1):

This problem already exists since TYPO3 v9. There is a [ticket in the bug tracker](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/87919) regarding this issue. I assume that in TYPO3 v12 `config. absRefPrefix` might be removed completely.

In the ticket comments you can find a number of hints, how to implement absolute links in various places:

- use `(NO/ACT/...).stdWrap.typolink.forceAbsoluteUrl = 1` for HMENU
- for links in the CKEditor RTE this config make every link absolute:

  ```
  lib.parseFunc_RTE.tags.a.typolink {
    forceAbsoluteUrl = 1
    forceAbsoluteUrl.scheme = https
  }
  ```
- if you want to globally rewrite all links to absolute links, you can implement the middleware [mentioned in the ticket](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/87919#note-11).

Comment: Thx. Please see my last comment in the ticket about introducing a new configuration option to enable absolute links based on site configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Since 12 LTS there is a new feature for this now:

https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/12.1/Feature-87919-AllowGenerationOfAbsoluteURLsCompletely.html#feature-87919-allow-generation-of-absolute-urls-completely